# Pie Chart in Cluster Popup - Arcgis

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I want to add a pie chart to the cluster popup template. Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you,
Raj

Comment: Hi Raj - what have you tried?  Have you read the [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post?  Including charts in popups is well documented in the arcgis-js-api docs.  If you create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with some data clusters, we can take a look at this.

Comment: Yes I've read the How to ask a good question. I am plotting the US Power plant data on the map and using cluster there. Now on the cluster popup I want to show a Pie chart that shows %of each fuel type available. Something like https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=popup-multipleelements
I am not using the Feature layer hosted on the Arcgis Server. 
Issue is I am not getting the fields which we should provide in `mediaInfos` 
We get only three right? `cluster_count` `cluster_type_fieldName` and cluster_avg_fieldName`

Comment: You;d be better off writing all that description and more in the question itself.  I'm sure you've checked out the docs on [PieChartMediaInfo](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-popup-content-PieChartMediaInfo.html).  You'll need to define a `ChartMediaInfoValue` with a `fields` property, which is a field from your featurelayer.  Also, make sure your featurelayer is defined with `outFields: ["*"]`.  Without more description its hard to give more help.